# unable to ceil array

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm trying to do a pagination page with this [tutorial](http://www.phpjabbers.com/php--mysql-select-data-and-split-on-pages-php25.html), but keep getting errors.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php include "common.php"; ?>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM actiongame"; 
    try 
    { 
    // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
    // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
    // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    }
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
    foreach($rows as $row):
    $total_records = $row;print_r($total_records);
    //just to see what is the $total_records
    // i get this reult with print_r : Array ( [COUNT(id)] => 2969 ) 
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 48);
    //but i get fatal error = =
    //Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\wamp\www\category.php on line
    print_r($total_pages);
    endforeach;
    unset($row);
    ?>
```

My question is, how do I set the `$total_records`

to `2969` and use the `ceil($total_record / 48)`?

Here is my `db` connect script common.php code:

```
// These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database 
$username = 'root'; 
$password = ''; 
$host = 'localhost'; 
$dbname = 'minigame'; 

// UTF-8 is a character encoding scheme that allows you to conveniently store 
// a wide varienty of special characters, like ¢ or €, in your database. 
// By passing the following $options array to the database connection code we 
// are telling the MySQL server that we want to communicate with it using UTF-8 
// See Wikipedia for more information on UTF-8: 
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

// A try/catch statement is a common method of error handling in object oriented code. 
// First, PHP executes the code within the try block.  If at any time it encounters an 
// error while executing that code, it stops immediately and jumps down to the 
// catch block.  For more detailed information on exceptions and try/catch blocks: 
// http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php 
try 
{ 
    // This statement opens a connection to your database using the PDO library 
    // PDO is designed to provide a flexible interface between PHP and many 
    // different types of database servers.  For more information on PDO: 
    // http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    // If an error occurs while opening a connection to your database, it will 
    // be trapped here.  The script will output an error and stop executing. 
    // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
    // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code 
    // (like your database username and password). 
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

// This statement configures PDO to throw an exception when it encounters 
// an error.  This allows us to use try/catch blocks to trap database errors. 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

// This statement configures PDO to return database rows from your database using an associative 
// array.  This means the array will have string indexes, where the string value 
// represents the name of the column in your database. 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

// This block of code is used to undo magic quotes.  Magic quotes are a terrible 
// feature that was removed from PHP as of PHP 5.4.  However, older installations 
// of PHP may still have magic quotes enabled and this code is necessary to 
// prevent them from causing problems.  For more information on magic quotes: 
// http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php 
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
{ 
    function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
    { 
        foreach($array as &$value) 
        { 
            if(is_array($value)) 
            { 
                undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $value = stripslashes($value); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
} 

// This tells the web browser that your content is encoded using UTF-8 
// and that it should submit content back to you using UTF-8 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

// This initializes a session.  Sessions are used to store information about 
// a visitor from one web page visit to the next.  Unlike a cookie, the information is 
// stored on the server-side and cannot be modified by the visitor.  However, 
// note that in most cases sessions do still use cookies and require the visitor 
// to have cookies enabled.  For more information about sessions: 
// http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php 
session_start(); 

// Note that it is a good practice to NOT end your PHP files with a closing PHP tag. 
// This prevents trailing newlines on the file from being included in your output, 
// which can cause problems with redirecting users.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to ceil an array, you can do it on a numeric value.

Try editing your query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS tot FROM actiongame";
```

And then your PHP code like this:

```
$total_records = $row['tot'];
```

Comment: thanks , it work , will set to accepted answer after 7minutes